# c# increasing numericUpDown1 by increments of 25 and nothing else

Tags: c#

I am trying to set the numericUpDown1 so it will only increase by increments of 25. I only want the numbers to increase by 25 and not allow other things. so for example I want 25, 50 75, 100. I don't want any other number lets say 26,51,76,101 also is increments of 25 but I dont want that. I just want increments that are able to divide by 25 basically.

Comment: you only tag c#, but what application is this? Desktop? And what control did you use?

Comment: The `NumericUpDown` has an `Increment` property you can set to 25. Is there some reason setting that property doesn't work for you?

Comment: @JohnG it just sets what the spin buttons += or -=, so the user can enter 7 and up to 32; neither are multiples of 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your NumericUpDown's Increment property to 25, then double click on it in the designer and put a ValueChanged event handler that constrains the input to a multiple of 25:

```
    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numericUpDown1.Value % 25 == 0) return;
        numericUpDown1.Value = Math.Round(numericUpDown1.Value / 25) * 25;
    }
```

The first line that checks `%25` isn't strictly necessary and can be removed if you're happy to rely on an NUD not raising a ValueChanged event if it is set to the same value that is currently displaying.

The flow of the code is:

- user types e.g. 7 into the box. ValueChanged fires.
- 7%25 is not 0
- the code rounds 7 down to 0 and sets the Value to 0.
- ValueChanged fires again (because we just changed the value)
- 0%0 is 0, the code returns from the second fire
- the code returns from the first fire

If you remove the mod check the code still returns because:

- user types e.g. 7 into the box. ValueChanged fires.
- the code rounds 7 down to 0 and sets the Value to 0.
- ValueChanged fires again (because we just changed the value)
- the code rounds 0 down to 0 and sets the Value to 0
- 0 is not a change in value so the event does not raise again
- the code returns from the second fire
- the code returns from the first fire

I've always preferred to put something in that I can see stops infinite firing if I change a control programmatically, but your preferences may differ

Comment: Also, please rename your controls after you drop them on a form. No one wants to read code that is practically obfuscated by being chock full of button37, label62. `_containerWeightNumericUpDown` would be heaps better than `numericUpDown1`

Comment: Yes, I noted that in my small tests, and I had a more complicated version of your solution. As your answer does, I wanted to round down when the remainder was less than 13 and up if it was 13 or greater. It wasn’t clear to me if the OP had considered this. Also, you may want to note that changing the NUDs value is going to re-fire the event. Granted, the value will then be divisible evenly so it is only re-fired once. I turned the event off just to keep it clean.

Comment: Yea, I tend not to detach and reattach handlers in favor of some programmatic route of stopping an infinite event handler firing.. it's actually technically not even needed in this case as the ValueChanged  doesn't raise if you set the value to the same as it already is, but putting it in is a guaranteed behavior rather than relying on that always being the case

Comment: I have to agree with you in this context, it clearly takes more steps to subscribe/un-subscribe the event than it would to simply execute the single `if` statement. Which we are guaranteed will divide evenly.